# Falco audit rules is not showing any alerts

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube, opa, falco

I trying to enable falco audit rules.
[https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-audit-log-falco/][1]
Iam following this blog to get enable k8s audit rules in falco .

Iam using minikube v1.22.0 Kubernetes v1.21.2. As mentioned in the blog I created a audit rule file and audit webhook config file in the path ~/.minikube/files/etc/ssl/certs.

**audit-policy.yaml**

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1beta1 # This is required.
kind: Policy
# Don't generate audit events for all requests in RequestReceived stage.
omitStages:
  - "RequestReceived"
rules:
  # Log pod changes at RequestResponse level
  - level: RequestResponse
    resources:
    - group: ""
      # Resource "pods" doesn't match requests to any subresource of pods,
      # which is consistent with the RBAC policy.
      resources: ["pods", "deployments"]
​
  - level: RequestResponse
    resources:
    - group: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
      # Resource "pods" doesn't match requests to any subresource of pods,
      # which is consistent with the RBAC policy.
      resources: ["clusterroles", "clusterrolebindings"]
​
  # Log "pods/log", "pods/status" at Metadata level
  - level: Metadata
    resources:
    - group: ""
      resources: ["pods/log", "pods/status"]
​
  # Don't log requests to a configmap called "controller-leader"
  - level: None
    resources:
    - group: ""
      resources: ["configmaps"]
      resourceNames: ["controller-leader"]
​
  # Don't log watch requests by the "system:kube-proxy" on endpoints or services
  - level: None
    users: ["system:kube-proxy"]
    verbs: ["watch"]
    resources:
    - group: "" # core API group
      resources: ["endpoints", "services"]
​
  # Don't log authenticated requests to certain non-resource URL paths.
  - level: None
    userGroups: ["system:authenticated"]
    nonResourceURLs:
    - "/api*" # Wildcard matching.
    - "/version"
​
  # Log the request body of configmap changes in kube-system.
  - level: Request
    resources:
    - group: "" # core API group
      resources: ["configmaps"]
    # This rule only applies to resources in the "kube-system" namespace.
    # The empty string "" can be used to select non-namespaced resources.
    namespaces: ["kube-system"]
​
  # Log configmap changes in all other namespaces at the RequestResponse level.
  - level: RequestResponse
    resources:
    - group: "" # core API group
      resources: ["configmaps"]
​
  # Log secret changes in all other namespaces at the Metadata level.
  - level: Metadata
    resources:
    - group: "" # core API group
      resources: ["secrets"]
​
  # Log all other resources in core and extensions at the Request level.
  - level: Request
    resources:
    - group: "" # core API group
    - group: "extensions" # Version of group should NOT be included.
​
  # A catch-all rule to log all other requests at the Metadata level.
  - level: Metadata
    # Long-running requests like watches that fall under this rule will not
    # generate an audit event in RequestReceived.
    omitStages:
      - "RequestReceived"
```

**audit-webhook-config.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: falco
  cluster:
    # certificate-authority: /path/to/ca.crt # for https
    server: http://127.0.0.1:32765/k8s-audit
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: falco
    user: ""
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
preferences: {}
users: []
```

I started my minikube with flags using this cmd

*minikube start   --extra-config=apiserver.audit-policy-file=/etc/ssl/certs/audit-policy.yaml   --extra-config=apiserver.audit-log-path=- --extra-config=apiserver.audit-webhook-config-file=/etc/ssl/certs/audit-webhook-config.yaml* .

But still my k8s-audit-rules(falco) is  not showing any alerts. Am I missing anything?